# Sphinx - achieving setFilter OR for sql_attr_uint

Tags: sphinx

sphinx.conf

```
sql_query           = SELECT item_id, item_title, item_time, cat_id, region_id, region_parent, region1, region2, region3, metro_id, group_id, doc_words, FROM articles;

sql_attr_uint           = cat_id
sql_attr_uint           = region_id
sql_attr_uint           = region_parent
sql_attr_uint           = region1
sql_attr_uint           = region2
sql_attr_uint           = region3
sql_attr_uint           = metro_id
sql_attr_uint           = group_id
sql_attr_timestamp      = item_time

sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM articles WHERE item_id=$id
```

php sphinx client

```
$cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED  );

// User choses either full text search for title or doc_words column
if ($user_column_selected == "titles")  
{
    $user_selected_table = "@item_title";
}
elseif ($user_column_selected == "@doc_words")  
{
    $user_selected_table = "@doc_words";
}

// User chose to filter by metro_id
$metro_array = explode(",", $selected_market_type);
$cl->SetFilter('metro_id', $metro_array);

// User chose to filter by category
$cat_array = explode(",", $selected_category);
$cl->SetFilter('cat_id', $cat_array);

// User chose to filter by a range of region_id
if ($user_region_range == "1")
{
    $cl->SetFilterRange('region_id', 100, 152, TRUE);
}
else
{
    /**** USER SELECTED A SPECIFIC REGION ****/
    $region_array = explode(",", $selected_region);
    $cl->SetFilter('region_id', $region_array);
}

// User chose to sort by time rather than relevance
if ($user_relevance == "1")
{   
    // by item time
    $cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, 'item_time');
}

// User chose to filter by time range
if ($user_date_filter == "1")
{
    $cl->SetFilterRange('item_time',$unix_date_from, $unix_date_to,$exclude=false);
}

// User choses to group results by group_id
if ($user_group == "1")
{
    $cl->SetGroupBy ( 'group_id', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, '@group desc' );
}

$sphinx_result = $cl->Query($user_selected_table." ".$user_text_query, my_sphinx_index );
```

With what I created above the user has the ability to perform full text search on item_title or doc_words, can narrow results by one or more of the sql_attr_uint columns that can be sorted by item_time and grouped by the group_id.

I can currently setFilter by any of my sql_attr_uint region columns as demonstrated above but what I need is boolean OR for those region columns.

I want to do so without losing any of the above functionality while adding some sort of "setFilter OR" for columns region_id, region_parent, region1, region2, region3.

I have read the setSelect and setFilter with mysql CONCAT example in the docs but does not make any sense to me when applying it to this kind of configuration.  What would be the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally would probably make a new MVA of regions

```
sql_query = ... cat_id, CONCAT_WS(',', region_id, region_parent, region1, region2, region3) AS regions, ...
sql_attr_multi = uint regions from field
```

Then its pretty easy to find documents with a particuar id in any of the columns :-)